# Web pages in CHtmlView with high dpi (150%) display incorrectly

Tags: html, c++, css, asp.net, mfc

**Problem**

I'm having the problem for days and haven't found anyone else mentioned it..

The issue is that when I set the **system dpi scaling to 150% or above, some webpages I open in CHtmlView would be messed up**, while using IE or Chrome not causing the same problem.

**Context**

It seems like in CHtmlView the fonts get bigger than it's needed. I figured out this situation happens if my program's "high DPI-aware" property is set. But I can't turn it off either because the webpage would be blurry.
The strange part is when I tested msdn or google paged in CHtmlView, they neither caused the problem nor scale 150%. They just displayed as the 100% one.

Not sure if I should do something to my program or the webpage. The webpage needed to be displayed in my program is also from my company, so if I know what to set in the webpage I could handle it.

Thank you :)

**Edit:**
Because the website I'm having problem with is a private site, so I use another page to explain the situation.

[Webpage in HtmlView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5w9O.png), seem like only fonts get bigger.

[Webpage in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoSQN.png)

Comment: I think that the problem is become from your web page, not from CHtmlView ... just try to render some simple page inside of your CHtmlView, with font 150%, and see what is happen ...

Comment: Can you explain more about how the website is "messed up"?  Also, do you have relevant code you can post (C++ and/or CSS)?

Comment: @philselmer Hi, I updated the question with some screenshots :) My c++ code is just a simple mfc program with CHtmlView. I wrote it to simply test this problem. I called Navigate2 in OnInitialUpdate(). Also I don't have the CSS code, because the webpage is written by another department.

Comment: @flaviu2 I didn't just scaled the font or zoom in. I set the system scaling in Win10 to 150%.

Comment: Is your DPI Awareness set to `None`?  You can find this setting in your project settings under "Manifest Tool -> Input and Output".  If it's set to `None`, Windows will handle adjusting the sizes of elements itself.  If you set it to `High DPI Aware` (default) or `Per Monitor High DPI Aware`, it should stop doing that (but you are expected to size your UI appropriately.

Comment: Browser control uses old version of IE engine by default. Set feature control registry key [`FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation) to use newer version of IE. Your problem may already go away.

Comment: @philselmer This problem only happens when I set DPI Awareness to High DPI Aware or Per Monitor High DPI Aware. I've tried to set it to None, and everything went right but blurry, which is not acceptable..

Comment: @zett42 Hi, I'm sorry that I'm not so familiar with FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION. Is it set by adding a DWORD value named my app's name through Regedit? I tried to add value 11001 but when I run the app and acquire the IE version by `RegQueryValueEx`, I still got `9`.. Thank you!

Comment: Replace "contoso.exe" that is used on the MSDN sample by the name of your executable. Your app could set this registry value programmatically in `InitInstance`. For that you have to write the value under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` (so users don't need administrator rights).

Comment: Here are a couple resources that might help out.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469266(v=vs.85).aspx   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd464659(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm here as I've got the same problem.

You can create a new VS2017 MFC project, derive a view from CHtmlView, you'll find this in the constructed code

```
void CMFCApplication4View::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    CHtmlView::OnInitialUpdate();
    Navigate2(_T("http://www.msdn.microsoft.com/visualc/"),nullptr, nullptr);
}
```

(Note I had to delete the two trailing nullptr arguments to get it to compile)

My application manifest lists the app as being High DPI Aware and I've got a 200% (192dpi) scaled monitor.

The web page that loads is tiny (unscaled).

zett42's answer (Aug 31 '17 at 14:39) is correct. Add the registry key indicated, using

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

MFCApplication4.exe=11001  [your application name here].
```

Restart the app, hey presto everythin is correctly scaled.

Dunno why I can't upvote zett42.